# Do I need to pass null as an argument for optional parameters in Javascript functions/methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, optional-arguments

Do I need to pass null as an argument for optional parameters?

For an example I have included code from the Mongoose documentation:

```
Model.find(conditions, [projection], [options], [callback])

// Example use
// passing options and executing immediately
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }, function (err, docs) {});
```

I have been successfully utilizing this method and other similar methods without passing null as the second argument, but I would like to know if this will get me into trouble down the road?

I have found some related questions, but they do not seem to be specific to optional parameters. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the function is written.

Take this function for example:

```js
function repeat(value, times) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    value = "Hello!";
    times = 2;
  } else if (arguments.length === 1) {
    if (typeof value === "number") {
      times = value;
      value = "Hello!";
    } else {
      times = 2;
    }
  }
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    output += value + " ";
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(repeat());
console.log(repeat("Yo!"));
console.log(repeat(5));
console.log(repeat("Yo Yo!", 3));
```

The arguments it expects are sufficiently different (in this case one is a string and one is a number) that it can test to see if the "first" argument is omitted even if the "second" argument is supplied.

---

The documentation you provided says:

> ```
> Model.find(conditions, [projection], [options], [callback])
> ```

Each of the last three arguments is shown as independently optional, which suggests that you can omit any of them and still supply the ones that follow.

Compare to [the MDN documentation for JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> ```
> JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
> ```

The third argument has `[]` around it to indicate it is optional, but it is **inside** the `[]` around the *second* argument. This means that you can specify the third argument only if the second argument is provided.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Adding up to your answer, in ES6 you can use destructuring to avoid the `arguments` call and make the code a little cleaner.

Comment: It turns out that not passing null as the projection argument caused my server to crash because my options object was being interpreted as a projection, so I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is correct, I just want to add up that in ES6 you can avoid that by [destructuring parameters](http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching).

I'll give you an example:

```
let str= "Something";
let num = 10;

doSomething({ str, num });

function doSomething({ somethingElse, num, str }) {
    /* the argument gets passed like 
    { 
        somethingElse: somethingElse, 
        num: num, 
        str: str
    }
    and if any value is missing then it is null, so you can check for
    each property's existance easily
    */
}
```

Comment: I just recently learned about destructuring, but had not yet observed its practical use. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Actually, the usage that you were asking for is its exact practical use, it's the most clean way to avoid having to do `foo(null, null, null, null, null, "finallySomeValue")` (even though I'd love for JS to have overloading, destructuring is pretty nice to have). You should give ES6 a try, as it has many of these little things that come in handy every now and then.